# Is the Stack Overflow for Teams help center (knowledge base) supporting Markdown?

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, stack-overflow-for-teams

The Stack Overflow for Teams [help center](http://www.stackoverflow.help/support/home) seems to have moved the help content from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of the main site. The content is not rendered correctly since it doesn't seem to support markdown.

Instances:

http://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000043579-searching-for-questions-and-answers

[image: first example of the help center]

- **Bold Italics** is rendered as `**bold italics**`.
- Code html tag, as well as backticks, are not rendered.

http://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042856-asking-a-question

[image: second example of the help center]

- Inline links are not rendered.

**So, the question is whether it is supposed to support Markdown or is there any plan to support formatting and links by any other means?**

Comment: If they have problems implementing a markdown-to-HTML conversion, they know where to ask :P

Comment: @usr2564301 Closed as duplicate ;)

Comment: I would assume 99.9% this is a bug.  I dont think anyone wants to say "if foo **bar** blah blah" and really expect those *'s to be there.

Comment: @JonH \* “if foo \*\*bar\*\* blah blah” :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From a look at the source, Stack Exchange Inc. appear to be using FreshDesk for this Help Center:

> [image]

Searching revealed [this six-year-old feature request to add Markdown support to FreshDesk](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/discussions/topics/793). The [latest official reply](https://support.freshdesk.com/support/discussions/topics/793/page/2#post-490936), three years ago, was the following:

> Hi everyone,
>
> Thanks for your feedback and reactions.
>
> Markdown is awesome - it fastens up the process and is easier (for
>   common tasks) than conventional text formatting. We couldn't agree
>   more.
>
> However markdown does have certain limitations (lack of
>   standardisation, unintentional formatting, user reach etc) that makes
>   us slightly apprehensive to include it in Freshdesk. While we
>   definitely can work around the limitations and build fixes, we are not
>   sure if it will justify the effort taken. So between implementing
>   markdown or alternatively, making our existing rich text editor more
>   functional and less error prone, we thought it best to first make our
>   rich text editor more robust. We are also working towards providing
>   more shortcut keys / combinations so the process becomes faster and
>   easier.
>
> Having said the above, we definitely intend to revisit markdown as a
>   feature sometime in the future - but for now have deferred it. Thank
>   you all for the suggestions and for your understanding.

It seems like support is not coming. Stack Exchange Inc. will need to manually convert these pages.

Comment: That clears somethings... It is weird for Stack Overflow to miss Markdown when it is used throughout the site and even will be used in Teams Q&A . Will accept this for now

Answer (score 2):

As Jeremy pointed out, we use Freshdesk for that portal and they do not support Markdown.

I've gone ahead and fixed all the Markdown that was still present in those couple pages, as well as one other. If you find any other pages that have unrendered Markdown that needs changed to HTML markup, let us know.

Comment: I think you missed one http://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042018-creating-new-tags `**` and backticks...